# Replicating Google Sheets like performance (handsontable)

Tags: jquery, performance, mongodb, spreadsheet, handsontable

I'm using handsontable + jQuery http://handsontable.com/ to embed a spreadsheet in a webpage.

While handsontable does a pretty good job of handling larger data sets, the problem for me is trying to pull in 100,000+ rows of data at once from MongoDB + insert them into the DOM takes up way too much time and memory.

I thought about an 'infinite scroll' solution that only keeps 2000 rows in at a time, then loads the next / or previous 2000, depending on the users vertical scroll.

But this seems a little kludgy because what if the user wants to set the 'price' column for the entire data set to 19.99...

So ultimately my question is how have other people handled this? What does Google Sheets do? Apparently the newest version supports 2,000,000 rows of data https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/2TNrpc9xExY

What are some high-level solutions to this?

Comment: 2 million cells, not rows, see: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/65788/29140

Answer (score 1):

Handsontables have amazing features but is yet slow.

If you take a look at this [link](https://github.com/handsontable/jquery-handsontable/wiki/JavaScript-&-DOM-performance-tips) you will notice that still it needs to fit in some standards to improve performance.

I suggest you to follow good practices like the these explained [here](http://gregfranko.com/jquery-best-practices/#/7)